# Eligibility for a PhD in Business Administration program

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am looking into PhD in Business program at various universities in North America, and I realized that many of those programs require their candidates to have "a Master's degree". If I have a non-thesis, course-based Master's degree, am I still meeting this minimum admission requirement? or by "Master's degree", did they mean a "thesis-based research Master's degree"?

Thank you

Comment: OP has also asked: [Can I be admitted into a PhD program with non-thesis MS degree?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18778/can-i-be-admitted-into-a-phd-program-with-non-thesis-ms-degree) the only difference being field of study. It's not clear to me whether two separate questions are really needed.

Comment: I don't know whether this will help, but I was accepted into the Heriot Watt DBA programme with an MBA.